# Express + Typescript ° TypeORM = TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined

Tags: typescript, typeorm, joincolumn

I am struggling, I have two entities linked by OneToMany (Marketplace -> Annonce), I can fetch the marketplace from annonce, but i can't fetch annonces from marketplace, It only works when it is eager but no way i make it from with lazy mode.
I tried everything.

If you can explain to me where this error come from, i would appreciate a lot.

[TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lev23.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I removed "private" from properties.